# $\int\sqrt{\sin(x)}(\cos(x))^3dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

**EDIT:** @Andrew Chin's comment solved the issue

$\int(\sin(x))^{1/2}(\cos(x))^3dx$

=$\int(\sin(x))^{1/2}(\cos(x))^2(\cos(x))dx$

=$\int(\sin(x))^{1/2}(1-\sin^2(x))(\cos(x))dx$

Let $u=\sin(x)$, therefore $du=\cos(x)dx$, next:

=$\int(u)^{1/2}(1-u^2)du$

=$\frac{2}{3}(u)^{\frac{3}{2}}-\frac{2}{5}(u)^{\frac{5}{2}}+C$, substituting $u=\sin(x)$ we get:

=$\frac{2}{3}(\sin(x))^{\frac{3}{2}}-\frac{2}{5}(\sin(x))^{\frac{5}{2}}+C$

Except this is incorrect (the derivative of my answer clearly isn't equal to the integrand), but I don't know why. Can someone tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: Should be $\frac72$ instead of $\frac52$.  Then the derivative of your answer will be equal to the integrand.  I'm interested, though; what is your technique in being able to immediately _clearly_ see they aren't equal?

Comment: @AndrewChin Ahh yes, thanks much! And I'm not able to see they aren't equal immediately, I graphed the answer I reached on Desmos as a function $f(x)$ and started a new line for $f^{'}(x)$ which it graphs immediately, then I graphed the integrand and compared. It wasn't my skill ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I have pointed out in a comment, the mistake comes from the power rule of integration.
\begin{align}
\int\sqrt{\sin x}\cos^3x\,dx&=\int\sqrt{\sin x}\cos^2x\cos x\,dx\\
&=\int\sqrt{\sin x}(1-\sin^2x)\cos x\,dx\\
&=\int\sqrt u(1-u^2)\,du\\
&=\int\sqrt u\,du-\int\sqrt{u^5}\,du\\
&=\frac23u^{3/2}-\frac27u^{7/2}+C\\
&=\frac23(\sin x)^{3/2}-\frac27(\sin x)^{7/2}+C.
\end{align}

Differentiating the final line to check, we get
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac23(\sin x)^{3/2}-\frac27(\sin x)^{7/2}+C\right)&=(\sin x)^{1/2}\cos x-(\sin x)^{5/2}\cos x\\
&=(\sin x)^{1/2}\cos x(1-\sin^2x)\\
&=\sqrt{\sin x}\cos x\cos^2x\\
&=\sqrt{\sin x}\cos^3x
\end{align}
as desired.

Comment: Sorry for not accepting answer earlier